# VS 2012 does not start webservice

Tags: asp.net, web-services, debugging, visual-studio-2012

### The problem was, that a file was missing, see comments below. Problem solved.

I migrated from VS 2010 to VS 2012.

Since then, when i start a web project which also has a webservice in it, the webservice is not reachable anymore. It was fine in VS 2010 and also works on an IIS server.

When i try to access the webservice at server/MyComService.svc i get a 404 error saying "The ressource cannot be found."

The webpage itself is working like expected.

Here is the definition of the service in the web.config, but since it works on a VS 2010 and an IIS server I cant think that there is an error in it:

```
    <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MyComService" behaviorConfiguration="WebServiceBehaviour" >
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebServiceBinding" contract="MyComServiceInterface">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WebServiceBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="4000000">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="4000000" maxBytesPerRead="4000000" maxArrayLength="4000000" />
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I also tried setting the address attribute of endpoint, but it still did not work.

Is there anything in the settings I need to change, or how can i get VS2012 to start the webservice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your svc file copied to the directory IIS is running the site from?

Comment: I am not debugging on an IIS. The problem happens on local debugging with the integrated webserver of VS 2012.

Comment: If you place a text file in the folder, is it served up? Are you using https by mistake?

Comment: This brought me to the solution. It seems like during converting the project from VS2010 to VS2012 i lost the .svn file. Since the .svn.cs file was in the project, i did not miss it. Thanks, works now.

Answer (score 0):

I tried something different based on the following information.

```
 Check to see if you have received the following update? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/894670
```